# Stop exposing framework resources

Tags: objective-c, swift, xcode, frameworks

I am working in a framework project where I am maintaining several json configuration files. While I am building the framework the files are visible in project.framework directory. But I don't want to expose that to the user. How I can do that.

Thank you.

Comment: You can create a project using Cocoa Touch Framework, so you can create you own framework and import to your project.

Comment: @JoséNeto thank you for your reply. yes i am already working on the framework project and everything working fine while I used it in main project. but some files in the framework is visible to the user/main app, i dont want to get these files to be visible to the user actually.

Comment: Sorry to say that you can not hide your framework resources as its public and not able to hide to other user.

Comment: Unfortunately,  you can not hide your JSON file Since the resource bundle is just a directory structure with some files there is not way to hide them.

Comment: A Framework *target* can also be it's own Xcode *project*. When you build your *project*, a **.framework** file is created. In a separate Xcode app *project*, simply add this **.framework** file. Of course, you'll need to redistribute this file every time you make changes to it.

Comment: thank you for answering, i got that.